# Should I wait for document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I am binding event handlers to `document`:

```
$(document).bind("myEvent", function() { ... });
```

Do I have to wait for the ready event (i.e. use `$(document).ready`) to bind event handlers in general and when I bind them to `document` in particular?

Comment: @PragneshChauhan: Why? I am not changing the DOM.

Comment: There is no reason to do so, but it might be better for consistency... it's your choice, do what you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: As its the norm, why would you *not* want to do it?

Comment: @FelixKling: So why is everyone downvote me??

Comment: @Naor i suggest your being downvoted as the documentation for jQuery is pretty exhaustive and would give you the answer

Comment: @FelixKling: If there is no reason to wait for the ready event, why is this the norm of such cases? I am not changing the DOM..

Comment: @Naor: See my other comment. I would not call it *norm*, it's just very common (is that what norm means?). It's important to know when you have to use it and when it's optional, and it can lead to more consistent code if you use it even if it it's optional. Note that I'm not saying that you should use it, I'm just explaining different points of view. IMHO, the way you ask the question make it sound a bit subjective. If you want to know whether it is necessary to guarantee that it works, phrase it accordingly.

Comment: @FelixKling: I know the documentation for jQuery is pretty exhaustive, I spent there many time and yet, there is nothing written there about waiting for events binding.

Comment: *"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; **they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call** to `.on()`."* http://api.jquery.com/on/ (any event handler shorthand method calls `.on` internally). The [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) says as well: *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that **we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready**."* (followed by an example).

Comment: @FelixKling: But I am asking about THE DOCUMENT(!) and not "some elements"! Therefore I asked this question, because it is not usual situation that is not documented. I hope I am more understandable now. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No, you should not, or at least you don’t have to. It’s just a waste of time and code since the document is available when javascript is executed.

Comment: To be fair, you just mentioned *"there is nothing written there about waiting for events binding"* in your last comment, so I responded according to that. It also seemed that you thought you only needed `$(document).ready` when you make changes to the DOM (which is not the case). I revised your question to make it more concrete. Feel free to revert/change/whatever it.

Comment: Think of like this: if the document wasn’t ready, you wouldn’t be able to bind a ready event in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(document).ready` is used to ensure the DOM is ready before trying to interact with it. If you put your script in the `<head>` then I suggest you put your code within this block if you interact with the DOM. If you put your script at the bottom of the `<body>` after the DOM elements then its not required - but I would still suggest its used.

**Update**

Attaching an event handler to the `document` doesn't require the code to be within the `ready` handler but its often used for consistency, some people (me included) place all script to attach event handers (regardless of the target) in a `ready` handler.

You will notice that on the documentation for `bind()` that elements must exist before the handler is attached.

> Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs.

Also note that `.on()` is the preferred and suggested method to use inplace of `.bind()` as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: Setting an event is not changing the DOM. Why should I wait until the document is ready? isn't it a tiny waste of time? Do it just because its the norm? (why is this the norm anyways?)

Comment: @Naor: Elements have to exist when you bind event handlers to them, so you actually have to wait until the DOM is ready. `document` exists at any time though, so waiting is not needed in this case.

Comment: @Naor I didnt say *changing* the DOM - i said interact with it - any interaction, such as binding an event. Ie you cannot bind an event to a DOM element if its not preset. You are attaching an event handler to the `document` so there is strictly no requirement in your case

Comment: Great, this is why I asked the question. To be sure I don't really have to wait to the ready event in order to attach events to the documents. But, after thinking again on all the situation, I don't really want to trigger those events is case the DOM is not ready because those events are related to operations on the DOM.

Comment: @Naur if you are doing DOM manipulations inside the event handler, I suggest you put the document ready listener where it’s needed (inside the handler).