# Calling onClick events

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm having a problem with my code, lemme first paste my code, most of it isn't important, just the context of it.

```
                $("#navbar > a").click(function(event) {
                $('#controls').show();
                var currentNum = parseInt($(this).attr('class'), 10);
                document.getElementById('pNum').innerHTML = "pg. " + (currentNum + 1);
                event.preventDefault();

                var t2 = ($(this).attr('id')).split("#");
                var $tr = $(zip.file(localStorage.selected + "/" + t2[0]).asText());
                document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = "";
                $('#main').append($tr);
                document.getElementById(t2[1]).scrollIntoView()
                current = ($(this).attr('class'));
                $(function() {
                    $("#main img").each(function() {
                        var imgPath = localStorage.selected + "/" + $(this).attr('src');
                        var imageData = zip.file(imgPath).asBinary();
                        $(this).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(imageData)); 
                    });

                });

                $("#main a").click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var elems = ($(this).attr('href')).split("#");
                    var $path = $(zip.file(localStorage.selected + "/" + elems[0]).asText());
                    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = "";
                    $('#main').append($path);
                });
            });
```

Now the click event at the bottom only works if I place it inside the code that creates the content, which shouldn't be the case and secondly it only works once, after I call it for the first time it refuses to work, any suggestions ?

Comment: why do you have a `document.ready` function and bind another click event handler inside the `$("#navbar > a").click` handler

Comment: @wirey as I said for some reason its the only place it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) instead.  For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#main a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var elems = ($(this).attr('href')).split("#");
    var $path = $(zip.file(localStorage.selected + "/" + elems[0]).asText());
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = "";
    $('#main').append($path);
});
```

The problem is that the `$('#main a').click(...)` approach requires that the `#main a` elements already be present on the page at the time that the click handler is bound.

Event delegation allows you to listen for a click event on the document (or any other element that will always be present), and see if that event originated from a `#main a` element.  This allows you to add/remove elements on the fly without worrying about which ones have or haven't already had click handlers bound.

Comment: I tried using the on() function, but for some reason it gave me the same problem, cause as the click function goes it clears the div and adds new content and it doesn't seem to pick that up.

Comment: If you used `$('#main a').on('click', ...)` you would definitely have the same problem.  `$(document).on('click', '#main a', ...`, on the other hand, should work.

Comment: @Crossman Yeah.. going through your code again this should fix your issue because this is binding directly to the document itself.

Comment: @wiray one question the, should the on function be outside of the doc ready function ?

Comment: @Crossman you are binding to the document itself so no it's not required. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13492047/1385672

Comment: @wirey Thanks its working now that its outside of the document.ready

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before, have you tried using this?:

```
$("<element id>").on( 'click', this, function ()
{
      // Your code here
}
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

edit*  Sorry did not see an answer before ( better explanation in answer above ) - but I'll keep mine for reference.